element.get_attribute('title') return empty
HTML:
<input id="arid_WIN_0_7" type="text" class="text " readonly="" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 122px; height: 21px; background-color: rgb(222, 224, 224);" title="Succès">

Code:
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"arid_WIN_0_7")))
title = element.get_attribute('title')
print(f"Intervention : {title}")


When I search using 'id' or 'type', I get a result, but when I search using 'title', it returns an empty result. Can you help me please?

Instead of EC.presence_of_element_located, try EC.visibility_of_element_located and see if that makes any difference.

EC.visibility_of_element_located => empty too

What do you mean by "search"? Do you mean get_attribute('id') works but get_attribute('title') doesn't?

Try this  :
title = browser.execute_script('return document.querySelector("[title=\'YourTitleHere\']").title;')
print(f"Intervention: {title}")


i try :
title = browser.execute_script('return document.querySelector("[title='arid_WIN_0_536871107']").getAttribute("title");')
but not succes

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[17]/div/input")))
title = element.get_attribute('id')
print(f"Intervention : {title}")
result with id :
Login réussi !
Intervention : arid_WIN_0_536870998
Recherche effectuée avec succès pour l'ID : 15253364
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Intervention : arid_WIN_0_536870998
Recherche effectuée avec succès pour l'ID : 15399541

I found
value = element.get_attribute('value')
